# Weird question mark in url when I change page using this.router.navigateByUrl or this.router.navigate

Tags: angular, router

Using Angular 12 I'm trying to do a simple navigation using this.router.navigateByUrl or this.router.navigate. I don't know why but in one case, after the navigation, a question mark comes up at the end of the url and it fires the refresh of the page.

[image]

Here the button that fires the method on template .html

```
<ng-template #topbarActions>
      <button mat-icon-button color="accent" grid-topbar-action (click)="addNewProductConversion()"
        [matTooltip]="'create' | translate">
        <mat-icon svgIcon="plus-box-outline" style="transform: scale(1.25);"></mat-icon>
      </button>
</ng-template>
```

Here the method with the navigateByUrl in it .ts

```
addNewProductConversion(): void {
  this.router.navigateByUrl(`/product/conversion/add/${this.productId}`);
}
```

Here the routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'conversion/add/:id', component: ProductConversionEditComponent }
```

The navigation move to the right page, but the question mark comes up during a second and refresh the page. After a second question mark disappears

Comment: whats in `this.productId` ? when you using `/product/conversion/add/1` is it still appear? I would suggest you also use `router.navigate` with `active route` this will be more generic to future changes. read more on  https://angular.io/api/router/Router

Comment: this.productId value is a different number depending on th product. In this case this variable value is simply 1